# Splitting cells based on 2 delimiters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, delimiter

I have an issue regarding with an excel file. I want to extract e-mails that is in between of `;` *semi-colon

Ex: `dubai,uae;funthat@gmail.com;calapan`

I want to separate `funthat@gmail.com` to a different column based on the semi-colons

Answer (score 1):

Use FILTERXML:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[contains(.,'@')]")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think the function doesn't work with Mac. But let me check with windows excel. Thank you <3